# How do I create and then declare a linked list in a linked list in c# using classes?

Tags: c#, linked-list

So, I'm trying to create a linked list inside each element of a linked list but I have no idea how to fill up the inner list with elements.

I first declare the outer list like this

```
RoomList<int> room = new RoomList<int>();
```

This is the class structure I use (not sure if even this is correct)

```
public class RoomList<T>
{
    DailyList head;

    public class DailyList
    {
        DailyListElement head;
        DailyListElement next;

        class DailyListElement
        {
            public T data;
            public DailyListElement next;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is a function I use to create a DailyList object

```
public void DailyListCreate()
{
    DailyList newDailyList = new DailyList();          
}
```

But I don't know how to add a DailyListElement. I hope this makes sense.

So I want to find out how to fill up the DailyList with DailyListElements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a linked list within a linked list based on your provided code. In there I have added the methods to add a new node and get all nodes at both levels (outer and inner linked lists). Please find the code below for the linked list structure as well as the client code:

The linked list structure

```
public class RoomList<T> where T : class
{
    private DailyList current;
    private DailyList head;

    public void Add(DailyList newItem)
    {
        if(current != null)
            current.next = newItem;
        current = newItem;
        if(head == null) 
            head = current;
    }

    public IEnumerable<DailyList> GetAllNodes() 
    {
        DailyList current  = head;
        List<DailyList> lst = new List<DailyList>();
        while (current != null) 
        {
            lst.Add(current);
            current = current.next;
        }
        return lst;
    }

    public class DailyList
    {
        public DailyList next;
        private DailyListElement head;
        private DailyListElement current;

        public void Add(DailyListElement newItem)
        {
            if(current != null)
                current.next = newItem;
            current = newItem;
            if(head == null) 
                head = current;
        }

        public IEnumerable<DailyListElement> GetAllNodes()
        {
            DailyListElement current  = head;
            List<DailyListElement> lst = new List<DailyListElement>();
            while (current != null) 
            {
                lst.Add(current);
                current = current.next;
            }
            return lst;
        }

        public class DailyListElement
        {
            public T data;
            public DailyListElement next;
        }
    }
}
```

The client code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var lst =new RoomList<string>();

        var upperNode = new RoomList<string>.DailyList();

        var element = new RoomList<string>.DailyList.DailyListElement();
        element.data = "first";
        upperNode.Add(element);

        element = new RoomList<string>.DailyList.DailyListElement();
        element.data = "second";
        upperNode.Add(element);

        lst.Add(upperNode);

        upperNode = new RoomList<string>.DailyList();

        element = new RoomList<string>.DailyList.DailyListElement();
        element.data = "third";
        upperNode.Add(element);

        element = new RoomList<string>.DailyList.DailyListElement();
        element.data = "fourth";
        upperNode.Add(element);

        lst.Add(upperNode);

        foreach(var item in lst.GetAllNodes())
        {
            foreach(var child in item.GetAllNodes())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(child.data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a method that will add a new element.

You could do this by traversing the elements until you reach the first one where next is null, then assign the new element to next. 
Or you could maybe also maintain a pointer to the last element and access it directly.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add methods `Add` to your `RoomList` and `DailyList` classes.

```
public class RoomList<T>
{
    public DailyList head;

    public DailyList Add()
    {
        var newItem = new DailyList();
        if (head != null) head.next = newItem;
        head = newItem;
        return newItem;
    }

    public class DailyList
    {
        public DailyList next;
        public DailyListElement head;

        public DailyListElement Add()
        {
            var newItem = new DailyListElement();
            if (head != null) head.next = newItem;
            head = newItem;
            return newItem;
        }

        public class DailyListElement
        {
            public T data;
            public DailyListElement next;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
var roomList = new RoomList<string>();
var dailyList = roomList.Add();
var dailyListElement = dailyList.Add();
dailyListElement.data = "StackOverflow rocks!";
Console.WriteLine(roomList.head.head.data);
```

Output:

> StackOverflow rocks!